# Unable to import the methods, even though external jar files are added to the project

Tags: selenium, testing

I created two classes under a package, first class is Login, second is forgotpassword. I added external jarfiles while writing my code to Login (1st class), it is successfully executing.

After that added new class to the same package (2nd class), but unable to import driver even though external jar files are present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where all selenium JARs? Can you show that screenshot?

Comment: @Helping hands, u can see under Referenced libraries

Comment: Sorry , but I can not see main Selenium JAR files in that list, For ex: Selenium standalone , selenium-java , selenium-java-src?

Comment: You can see now, all the added jar's

Comment: Still you are missing selenium standalone jar.

Comment: oh!! how to add it. but in login class, imported from these jar files only.

Comment: Download selenium standalone jar from here : [Selenium Standalone Jar](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and add it to library.

Comment: Thank u this helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screenshot , you are missing Selenium standalone JAR file to import , Kindly download from [Selenium Standalone JAR](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and import it then check in your code , it will allow you to use driver.

Comment: Again the above issue arises. Not able to figure it out. I added many projects & deleted too same issue is arising. @Helping hands please help

Comment: Is there any other jar files i should add. this issue arises, when i add multiple Class to the same project or creating new Java projects. Am i missing out anywhere

Comment: See if you are using multiple class in same project then either you will have to declare webdriver in all class or you can declare webdriver as static in one class and access it in another class.